# How to access variable with dot in name

Tags: typo3, fluid

I'm having trouble accessing an array key in Fluid. The array key name is "common.title". How can I access the value? Escaping the dot is not working. I know it's not good to have a dot in a key name, but the values come from a different source. See the attached image for more information.

[image: Array]

Comment: I had that, and I know I solved that. At least with TYPO3 v8. But hell yeah, I cannot remember where i did that nor how ... I'll search my brain (and gitlab). It was a quite simple solution AFAIR.
But in any case it's maybe useful for you to know, that this is possible at least.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try with escaping the `.` by using `common\.title`?